# How to create an "internal" api for my library which is not exposed to the user?

Tags: object-oriented-design, api, encapsulation, access-modifiers

**Note that my question is not platform specific so that's why I don't add the [kotlin] tag (the code is in Kotlin). If there is a Kotlin-specific answer I'd like to hear about it though**

I am working on a simple component (GUI) library and I have the following interfaces:

```
interface Component : Drawable, Positionable, Identifiable {

    fun getComponentStyles() : ComponentStyles

    fun setComponentStyles(componentStyles: ComponentStyles)

}

interface Container : Component {

    fun addComponent(component: Component)
}
```

Internally I have some base classes which implement the common functionality (`DefaultComponent`, and `DefaultContainer`). My problem is that I have some methods which I would not like to expose to the external world like:

```
fun fetchComponentByPosition(position: Position): Optional<out Component>
```

I can use `DefaultComponent` internally but the problem is that the user is able to call `addComponent` which will add a `Component` to a `Container` and obviously a `Component` is not a `DefaultComponent`. I can make an other `interface` which is implemented by `DefaultComponent` but it won't solve the problem which is *invariance* here.

Currently I have `Builder`s for all `Components` and all `Component` implementations use `DefaultComponent` as a base class so I can cast `Component` to `DefaultComponent` salfey but this is a hack at best.

So my question is this: *how can I hide the internal API when I have to use **invariant** interfaces (by invariant I mean that I both return and accept classes with a specific `interface` and I can't downcast them safely).?*

Comment: C# (and Kotlin) uses `protected` for this.  Declarations marked `protected` are  only visible to the inheriting class (if I understand your problem correctly).

Comment: You can't use the `protected` keyword in an interface in Kotlin (nor in Java). All methods in an `interface` are inherently `public`

Comment: Why would you want that in an interface?  Interface members are public by nature.

Comment: I have some methods which are used internally in my library so it is effectively public for all internal classes but I don't want my **users** to see them in order to have a clean API.

Comment: Can you declare a separate `internal` interface for your internal methods?

Comment: Also, what prevents you from simply calling the class' `internal` or `protected` methods directly?  Do you have multiple implementations of each class?  Are the interfaces necessary for unit testing?

Comment: The interfaces are necessary because the user can add *any* `Component` to a `Container` (for example `Label`s, `Button`s, etc). I have to offer an interface which can accept all of them. All implementations of `Component` inherit from a base class (`DefaultComponent`) which has some methods which are used internally (for example to find a `Component` by its position like in the example). My problem is that I do not want my users to see these methods, but I want to be able to use them within my lib.

Comment: The problem with `internal` interfaces is that a `public` interface can't inherit from an `internal` interface.

Comment: To answer your question about the `internal`/`protected` methds: I receive a `Component` and I need to cast it to `DefaultComponent` in order to get access to the methods I want.

Comment: So essentially your question boils down to "how can I have an interface be both `public` and `private` at the same time?"

Comment: No I can accept any solution which solves this problem in any way which is not a hack but probably it will involve interfaces.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to deal with a class API internally, not an interface API.  This would give you a bit more flexibility with respect to visibility.  You don't seem to need the capabilities that internal interfaces would provide; you would only need them if you intend to swap implementations, or have an especially complex inheritance tree.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. Can you elaborate with an example? Do you suggest that I should keep using type casting? The inheritance tree is very flat there are only 2 base classes.

Comment: I am trying to say that I don't understand why you're not just calling the methods on the internal classes directly, instead of going through a semi-private interface.

Comment: Because I receive `Component` objects from the external world and I need to cast them to `DefaultComponent` in order to do so. I can't expose `DefaultComponent` to the external world because it contains methods which would pollute the external api.

Comment: Then I'm afraid your stuck.  You can't declare that something publicly exists (which is what you need to make the `DefaultComponent` cast succeed) while at the same time disavowing its existence, unless the cast occurs *inside* your library within a suitable scope.  You have to find something that can be declared with an `internal` scope, which is why I was suggesting that you use an abstract class.

Comment: In any case, your statement "I receive a `Component` and I need to cast it to `DefaultComponent`" suggests that `DefaultComponent` is *already public.*  Otherwise, how would your code know how to cast it, unless your component already inherited from `DefaultComponent`?

Comment: Robert hits the nail on its head with the internal visibility-modifier for C#. I don't think you can do what you're asking in Kotlin: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/interface-method-in-kotlin-should-support-protected-internal-visibility-modifier/1918/6

Comment: I know that `DefaultComponent` is public but when my user presses `Ctrl+Space` when he works with a `Component` in his IDE he will see all the methods if I add them to `Component`. This is just a code "user experience" issue whic I'd like to solve in an elegant way.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9086136